# Firebug net panel server side

Tags: html, web-services, firebug

Is there a way to get the type of Firebug net panel functionality on a server.  I would like to be able to know which sites are being loaded when I load a page.  So, for example, when I load cnn.com, it loads pages from some advertising networks, facebook, etc.

Comment: It depends on your server side technology. What is the OS ? What is the application server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Firebug is great, for looking at traffic I suggest using Tamper Data, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/. It's a great Firefox plugin that shows you lots of information of everything thats going in and out of your Firefox window.

Comment: is there a way to automate the data collected for multiple websites?

Comment: Did a little searching and found this, http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/automate-and-extend-firefox-with-the-chickenfoot-add-on/636 Not sure if it's what your looking for though.